# What's the original Chinese to “To one who has seen too little of the world, everything is strange.”?

Tags: translation

In the English translation of [*Slapping the Table in Amazement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapping_the_Table_in_Amazement) there's an interesting phrase that shows up:

> ## Preface [1628 Edition]
>
> As the saying goes, “To one who has seen too little of the world, everything is strange.”

[ctext](https://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=gb&res=9051&remap=gb) & [Wikisource](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh/%E5%88%9D%E5%88%BB%E6%8B%8D%E6%A1%88%E9%A9%9A%E5%A5%87) both only start at "chapter" one. There doesn't seem to be a preface.

What's the original Chinese for: `“To one who has seen too little of the world, everything is strange.”`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[中国古典文学](http://www.zggdwx.com/chuke/0.html) has the preface.

Here's the first paragraph:

> ## 初刻拍案惊奇
>
> 凌濛初
>
> ## 序
>
> 语有之：“少所见，多所怪。”今之人，但知耳目之外，牛鬼蛇神之为奇，而不知耳目之内，日用起居，其为谲诡幻怪非可以常理测者固多也。昔华人至异域，异域咤以牛粪金；随诘华之异者，则曰：“有虫蠕蠕，而吐为彩缯锦绮，衣被天下。”彼舌挢而不信，乃华人未之或奇也。则所谓必向耳目之外索谲诡幻怪以为奇，赘矣。

The translation of `“To one who has seen too little of the world, everything is strange.”` is:

> 少所见，多所怪

There is also an entry for this in **ABC Proverbs** which says:

> Lit [Things (which are)] seldom seen [are felt to be] strange.
> Note Cf. the preface to Chū Kè Pāi'àn Jīngqì; now more commonly said shǎo jiàn, duō guài; see also the preceding entry.

Like the definition mentions the more, modern, common variant of this phrase is 少见多怪 which **ABC** defines as:

> The less one has seen, the more one marvels.

---

**ABC Proverbs** also contains the old phrase with an added sentence:

> 少所见多见怪，睹橐驼谓马肿背。
>
> Lit [One who has] seen little regards many things as strange; [(s)he] sees a camel [and] calls [it a] horse with a hunchback.

Comment: 少见多怪 is a common phrase for saying someone is ignorant, uninformed on a subject

Answer (score 0):

if you answer your own questions, we have nothing to do! I'll go get in the soup kitchen queue.

http://www.xiexingcun.net/3y2p/04/mydoc001.htm

语有之：“少所见，多所怪。”

The Chinese is definitely more succinct!